# Wrong serialization JSON in String field

Tags: android, json, quickblox

I'm developing app using QuickBlox services. I have String field with JSON in content. This is my JSON:

```
{"answers":[[{"name":"first"}],[{"name":"second"}],[{"name":"third"}],[{"name":"fourth"}],[{"name":"fifth"}],[{"name":"sixth"}]]}
```

Here is problem. When I want to get my field with JSON from QBCustomObject, it is serialized to this (without quotes and square braces):

```
[{
answers :
{
name : first
},
{
name : second
},
{
name : third
},
{
name : fourth
},
{
name : fifth
},
{
name : sixth
}
}]
```

What can I do in this situation?

I found in QBCustomObjectDeserializer class that code:

```
if(value.contains("[")) {
                String[] values2 = value.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace("\"", "").split(",");
```

Can I change rules of deserialization in QuickBlox SDK? Can I use my own deserializer?

Anyone can help resolve my problem please?

Comment: Why square braces for every curly braces ?

Comment: Because it could contains many fields in every block. It is required for me.

Comment: A pair of curly braces can have many items in it

Comment: It's not my problem. It's not important. My problem is serialization in QuickBlox.

Comment: I might add that on iOS it works perfectly. 0 problems with serialization.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in development branch
https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/tree/development

will be rolled out in our next upcoming release